# Get An Object From NodeJS to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object in backend side. This is how i send these objects to html

```
res.render('product', {title:title, allCategories : allCategories, product : product[0]})
```

I need to send product object to angularJs so i can make some operations with it. Product has multiple colors in it. I need to list them in dropdown menu with using angularjs.

```
    <div id='image' ng-controller="productColor">
      <select>             
          <option value="color" ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color}}</option>
      </select>     
    </div>
```

This is my angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('product', []);

app.controller('productColor',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/mens/mens-clothing/mens-clothing-suits/25604524'
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {  

        $scope.colors = response.product
        console.log(response.product)
    });

}]);
```

I made up that url. But when i go to that url, first part starts.

Thanks

-Edit : response.product returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

In your angular code, you are creating an Array that has an Array at it's first index:

```
$scope.colors = [
    response.product.colors
]
```

Change that bit to

```
$scope.colors =  response.product.colors;
```

and it should work for you:

```js
app.controller('productColor',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/mens/mens-clothing/mens-clothing-suits/25604524'
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {  
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.product)

        $scope.colors = response.product.colors;
    });

}]);
```

```html
<div id='image' ng-controller="productColor">
      <select>             
           <option value="color" ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color}}</option>
      </select>     
</div>
```

You are currently trying to use this code to send data as JSON to your angular script:

```
res.render('product', {title:title, allCategories : allCategories, product : product[0]})
```

But this does not create a JSON formatted response. As the Express Documentation says:

> Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.

What you want to use is the `json()` method of the `res` object

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

The code would look like this:

```
res.json({title:title, allCategories:allCategories, product:product[0]});
```

Comment: It obviously doesn't work here because of the URL not existing, and `app` being unset _in the snippet_

Comment: No problem i understand

Comment: Ah response.product returns undefined

Comment: You wrote that you made up the URL, so there wont be a response anyway

Comment: when i go to that url res.render('product', {title:title, allCategories : allCategories, product : product[0]})
part works :/

Comment: res.render doesn't send JSON data, it sends HTML. Are you using `res.render('product', {title:title, allCategories : allCategories, product : product[0]})` to render `http://localhost:3000/mens/mens-clothing/mens-clothing-suits/25604524`??

Comment: Yeah yeah as you said

Comment: I'll add that to my answer!

Comment: Thanks, im waiting

Comment: added it. Note that this is not the only way to do it, but the easiest

Comment: I understand what we must use json but this time how can i print html page :/

Comment: You *render* HTML (a website) using `res.render()` you send *JSON* to the client using `res.json()`. Your Webpage needs a renderer, and your API (where you get your JSON data) needs a function to send the JSON